# return sms to persian language in Java

Tags: java

Im using API for sending SMS of product query and taking variable from properties file in java.

I need to convert the output message to utf-8 as i need to send SMS of Persian language, please help me.

here is the code:

```
  List<String> returnMessage = new ArrayList<String>();
  Properties messagePack = new Properties();
          messagePack.load(RoshanSendSMS.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(String.format("%spack.properties", language)));

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray objArray = (JSONArray) parentObject.get("PurchasedOfferArray");
            int size = objArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) objArray.get(i);
                if (!obj.has("CatalogItemId")) {
                    continue;
                }

                String catalogId = obj.get("CatalogItemId").toString();

                String productId = messagePack.getProperty(catalogId);
                if (productId == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                String newProductId = "ProductName" + productId.split("t")[1];

                String msg = messagePack.getProperty(newProductId);
                if (msg == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!returnMessage.contains(msg)) {
                    returnMessage.add(msg);
                }

            }

            if(returnMessage.size()>0){
                returnMessage.add(0, messagePack.getProperty("PRE_MSG"));

                String fullMsg = String.join(" ", returnMessage);
                System.out.println("Message: "+ fullMsg);
            }else{
                System.out.println("No message found");
            }



            return "SUCCESS";
```

Comment: Where is the "output message"? I only see code that parses JSON. *"convert the output message to utf-8"*

Comment: It is difficult to work out what your question is, are you getting an error? Are you asking how to convert `returnMessage` into utf-8? If so I suspect you will find that easier to google that directly.